# Powershell syntax help needed

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell command that for automation purposes in our monitoring system, I'm trying to write in one line.

Basically, we're checking multiple Hyper-V virtual machines to make sure they are replicating properly.  The way we're doing this is checking the last replication date/time and comparing it to the current date/time.  Here's the one-liner I have for checking one machine.

```
(new-timespan -start(get-vm termserv002| Measure-VMReplication | select -expand lastreplicationtime)).totalminutes
```

This works perfectly.  However, we'd like to check ALL of the VMs on this Hyper-V box.  I can do this without running the new-timespan by running this command -

```
get-vm | where {$_.replicationstate -ne "Disabled"} | Measure-VMReplication | select vmname, lastreplicationtime
```

This gives me every VM on the box and its last replication time.

Ultimately, what I'd like for output is the VMName and LastReplicationTime in minutes from current date/time.  If I can do this on one line, homerun!

Any suggestions?  No matter how I try to meld the two together, I just can't seem to get the syntax right (Or it's not possible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it but give this a try:

```
get-vm | where {$_.replicationstate -ne "Disabled"} | Measure-VMReplication |
    select vmname, @{n="LastReplicationTime";e={ (new-timespan -start ($_.lastreplicationtime) -end (get-date)).TotalMinutes }}
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick!  I may have some more tweaking to go, but I'll open a new thread if I do!  THANKS!!

Comment: OK - follow-up - not sure of protocol.  If I need to open another question, let me know.  Any easy way to just show the vms where lastreplication time > say 1?

Comment: add this `| ? { $_.lastreplicationtime -gt 1 }` after the code above.

Comment: OUTSTANDING!  Thanks so much, exactly what I needed!  I couldn't figure that part out for the life of me - so simple, I didn't think I could use $_.lastreplicationtime at that point since we were into expressions.